# Thousand separator for number field in "Tab with table" display

Tags: drupal, custom-fields

My custom field is a "number text" displayed in a tab with table. For example it's displayed 123456789.99 but I need thousand separators, I mean that I'd like to read 123,456,789.99
How can I add this feature ?
I use CiviCRM 4.6.5 with the drupal version 7.38.
Regards,
Hashkey

Answer (score 3):

Check the settings at Administer/Localization? There is a setting for thousands separator!
[image]

Comment: Hello and Thank you ErikH. I did it but the separators doesn't appear for currency field in a "tab with table" display :(

Comment: So I would like to add separators for number fields and not only for currency fields but I don't know how...

Comment: Hello, no idea ???

Comment: I get the distinct impression that you feel it is my job to solve your problem? :-)

Comment: If you want to show the field on a specific tab, you could possibly use the summary hook (http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_summary) to have your own formatting?